# How to identify a country from a normalized phone number?

Tags: phone-number, country-codes

I have a list of international phone numbers and a [List of Country calling codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_country_calling_codes).
I would like to identify the Country from the numbers but I can't find a fast and elegant way to do it.

Any idea? The only I got is to have an hardcoded check (Eg. "look at the first number, look at the second number: if it's X then check for the third number. If the second number is Y then the Country is Foo", etc.).
I'm using PHP and a DB (MySQL) for the lists, but I think that any pseudocode will help.

Comment: No, that's pretty much the way to do it. Come up with a file format to make it easier to update that list.

Comment: How are the phone numbers given to you? Do you know the calling code or are they all part of just one number?

Comment: mm why not querying directly the prefix?

Comment: @birryree: I have a table in MySQL and each row is a normalized number. Why are you asking that?
@Eric: what do you mean? Can you please be more clear?

Comment: @Paolo - if you had the country codes separate from the phone numbers, then the look ups would be much easier (of course, if you had that you could also just have a field in the table for country of origin derived from the country code).

Comment: @Paolo I would tackle this by having a table with two columns one for the prefix the other for the country.  Then extract the prefix and query the database to get the country.

Answer (score 7):

Alternatively, you could use a tool like [Twilio Lookup](https://www.twilio.com/lookup).

The `CountryCode` property is always returned when you make an API request with Lookup.

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/lookups#lookups-instance-properties

[*Disclosure: I work for Twilio*]

Comment: You could be contributing to the community by flagging these for closure as duplicates...

Comment: I'm using Twilio version 3.4.1.0 and for my application update this library is not an option for now. Is there any way to get this info using that version?? Thanks

Comment: I mean twilio client.

Answer (score 2):

i was after something similar to this, but i also wanted to determine the region/state - if available. in the end i hacked up something based on a tree of the digits leading digits (spurred on by the description at [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_country_calling_codes))

my implementation is [available as a gist](https://gist.github.com/yee379/7037873).

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently using an implementation of [Google's libphonenumber](https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber) in Node, which works fairly well. I suppose you could try a PHP implementation, e.g. [libphonenumber-for-php](https://github.com/giggsey/libphonenumber-for-php).

Comment: You need to specify the country to check is is valid phone number from that country.

Comment: @gdfgdfg if you look at the Geocoder example in the GitHub page, it looks like it can derive the city (and hopefully also the country) from a phone number.

Answer (score 0):

The hard-coded check can be turned into a decision tree generated automatically from the list of calling codes. Each node of the tree defines the 'current' character, the list of possible following characters (tree nodes) or a country in case it's a terminal node. The root node will be for the leading '+' sign.

Comment: @downvoter is kindly asked to comment on what they see as wrong with my answer. The OP's problem is commonly solved using a [prefix tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) which I described in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The challenge here is that some countries share the same phone country code. E.g. both Canada and the US have phone numbers starting with +1.

I'm using https://github.com/giggsey/libphonenumber-for-php as following:

```php
/**
 * Get country
 * @param string $phone
 * @param string $defaultCountry
 * @return string Country code, e.g. 'CA', 'US', 'DE', ...
 */
public static function getCountry($phone, $defaultCountry) {
    try {
        $PhoneNumberUtil = \libphonenumber\PhoneNumberUtil::getInstance();
        $PhoneNumber = $PhoneNumberUtil->parse($phone, $defaultCountry);
        $country = $PhoneNumberUtil->getRegionCodeForNumber($PhoneNumber);
        return $country;
    } catch (\libphonenumber\NumberParseException $e) {

    }
    return $defaultCountry;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can easily do a simple lookup starting with the first number, then the second, and so on until you find it. This will work correctly because no calling code is a prefix of another code, i.e. the international calling codes form a "[prefix code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_code)" (the phone system relies on this property).

I'm not good any good at PHP so here is a simple python implementation; hopefully it is easy to follow:

```
>>> phone_numbers = ["+12345", "+23456", "+34567", "+45678"]
>>> country_codes = { "+1": "USA", "+234": "Nigeria", "+34" : "Spain" }
>>> for number in phone_numbers:
...     for i in [2, 3, 4]:
...         if number[:i] in country_codes:
...             print country_codes[number[:i]]
...             break
...     else:
...         print "Unknown"
...
USA
Nigeria
Spain
Unknown
```

Essentially you have an associative array between prefixes and countries (which I assume you can easily generate from that Wikipedia article. You try looking up the first digit of the phone number in the associative array. If it's not in the array you try the first two digits, then the first three. If there is no match after three digits then this number doesn't start with a valid international calling code.

Comment: It's not quite so simple. Most North American countries share the country code of 1 (USA, Canada, Bahamas, etc.). Also Russia and Kazakhstan both use 7. You should use a more sophisticated tool. I wrote one in ruby that could likely be easily ported to PHP: 
* https://github.com/bowsersenior/itu_codes