# detect country code by a given phone number in javascript

Tags: javascript, country-codes

I have an object with all available country codes. and I want to know how I can get the country code by a given phone number and display the corresponding country name. the phone number will look like 16041234567(Canada/US +1) or maybe 8601012345678(China +86) or any other country phone number without plus(+) in the front. I just want to get the country code then I know how to display the name. looks like the code can be 1 up to 4 digits.

Comment: I suggest you make an attempt, then show us know what you tried and what went wrong. [This SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4494818/how-to-identify-a-country-from-a-normalized-phone-number) might be helpful.

Comment: tried, can not figure it out. that is the reason I ask here

Comment: Sorry to hear that. What did you try? Unfortunately, "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include **attempted solutions**, **why they didn't work**, and the expected results." Give it a shot, you've got nothing to lose.

Answer (score 4):

FIRST ANSWER:

Just a quick thought, why not count from the other side.

take the 10 numbers off the back side of the number. What you are left with will be the truncated country code.
from your example:

`num = "16041234567";
code = num.slice(0, num.length-10);
country_name = country_code_object[code];`

This code assumes that your object can deal with variable length codes (but you could always buffer the front of the code if you needed to.

BROKEN: China does not use 10 number (cells use 11)

FIX:
After looking into country codes more completely I relised they are a prefix tree. This means that for a liner time you can just check character by character

```
num = "16041234567";
country_code;
i = 1;
while (!country_code || i < num.length) {
    country_code = country_code_obj[num.slice(0, i)];
    i++;
}
```

The nature of country codes will guarantee that the first code that works will be the correct one. (and we can imagine that this must be true, the phone company doesn't know when you are done typing numbers. They just know when you've reached the end of a valid country code)

Comment: the phone number will be not always 10 digit. see the chinese phone number

Comment: I stand corrected. Thanks eded. I have only spent time traveling in Europe and N. and  S. America. So I guess my answer won't work in that case.

Comment: The || statement should be changed to &&. Otherwise loop will run forever if country_code_obj does not contain the country code, or there is no country code in the number